# Jquery validations for select box drop-down

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery validations for my form. I'm trying to add validation for already stored values in the form. I have form with select box drop down fields such as select state, select city and I have jQuery file for list of all state and city from which I'm getting dynamic values to the select box drop-down.

When I add validations to file I'm not getting values of drop-down box. Here's is my code:

```
<form id="defaultForm" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('Hotel/Updatehotel'); ?>" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <a href="#" class="add_page_button">Edit Hotel<span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="box-content box">
        <input type="hidden" name="adminId" value="<?php echo $edithotel[0]->admin_id;?>">
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div id="selection">            
    <input type="hidden" name="selct_state" id="select_state" value="<?php echo $edithotel[0]->state; ?>">      
    <select class="selectBox form-control" name="state" id="listBox" onchange='selct_district(this.value)'>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="hidden" name="selct_city" id="select_city" value="<?php echo $edithotel[0]->city; ?>">
    <select class="selectBox form-control" id='secondlist' name="city">
    <option>Select City</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the jQuery validation code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#defaultForm").validate({
        rules: {
            state:{
                required: true,

            },
            city:{
                required: true,

            },
            agree: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            state: "Please enter hotel name !",
            city: "Please enter branch name !", 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And script for getting select values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var state =  document.getElementById('select_state').value;
    if(state){
        $('#listBox').val(state).attr('selected', true);             
    }           
    selct_district(state);
    setTimeout(sel_city, 0.1);
    sel_city();

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sel_city(){
    var city =  document.getElementById('select_city').value;
    if(city){
        $('#secondlist').val(city).attr('selected', true);           
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using any jquery plugin for select ?

Comment: @ Mayank Pandeyz   Here is the plugin:      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: I am asking about the select plugin ?

Comment: Oh ! I'm sorry i misunderstood the question, using this plugin:  https://github.com/marcj/jquery-selectBox

Comment: So this is the issue, every such plugin hides the selectbox and create there custom one and validation do not works on that. Check the DOM

Comment: What do i need to check and where ? can you tell me please

Comment: Thanks  @mayank . it is working for adding values to form file, but not working for already selected values. I'm not getting drop-down values